# Azure Service Bus Session Queue: AcceptMessageSession() takes from few ms to more than few minutes without Service Bus Timeout exception

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-webjobs, asp.net-core-2.1, azure-servicebus-queues

I am trying to read messages from Azure Service Bus Session Queues in Azure environment through the Azure Continuous Web Jobs using .Net core 2.1. But for reading the session from queue it will take more than one or two minutes even though the session present in it.

I think there is problem with AcceptMessageSessionAsync() function.

```
   IMessageSession session;
   sessionClient = new SessionClient(_serviceBusSettings.Value.Connection, _serviceBusSettings.Value.PullQueueName);
   sessionClient.OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
   session = await sessionClient.AcceptMessageSessionAsync();
```

My business logic like

1.Receive the session

2.Process message from the session

3.Execute the business logic with message

4.Complete the message from session

2,3 and 4 steps run continuously until all messages received from 
session.
5.Next read other session

Can anyone suggest me how to resolve the above issue?

Thanks!